# Resize content frame in webView without modifying UIWebView frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

How the content frame (say for example text) in `UIWebView` can be modified?

Please check the below image which explains my requirement.

[image: Attached image]

In the above image, the box with yellow border is `UIWebView` frame and in red is its content(`HTML text in webView`).The black line(near yellow box) is where the `scroll bar` should come. So what I need is, only decrease the content width of `UIWebView` without changing `webView's` frame and setting the `scroll bar` at the right edge of the `webView`.

Is it possible to achieve?

Please share your ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: Use HTML .. make **<div>** with specific width, set your content inside this **<div>** then load that html string to `UIWebView`.

Comment: @TheTiger: Thank you.Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[webView setOpaque:NO];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSString *htmlString = @"<html>\
                        <body>\
                        <div style='width:33%; color:white; background-color:black; margin:0px auto; text-align:center;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</div>\
                        </body>\
                        </html>\
";

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

1. Black view is **contentView** or any **div**.
2. Red View is your `webView`.
3. `margin:0px auto;` property make that **div** centered.
4. You can change **contentView**'s width according to you. See `width:33%` in **div** tag.

**And the result is:-**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Use `text-align:` property in **div** 'text-align:center'. For more html code visit [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: No its not working.This is my code: NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
 "body {font-family: \"Helvetica\"; font-size:14; color:white;}"
 "</style><head><body><div style= width:250; text-align:center;%@></div></body></head></html>",infoObj.description];

Comment: Probably you're doing something wrong ... see updated answer.

Comment: Is there any mistake in above code? Its not working.I assigned the "htmlString" directly to webView.

Comment: Dude I'm not an html developer I just know a little. You have set head and text/css in your code which is not in my code.

Comment: Ok Thank you.I will find and update to you.Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: Hai using these two properties solved my problem. "position: absolute;left: 10;". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The UIScrollView property is available for UIWebView starting in iOS 5. You can use that to resize your view by implementing the webViewDidFinishLoad: message in your delegate, like this:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGRect newBounds = webView.bounds;
    newBounds.size.height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    webView.bounds = newBounds;
}
```

Or

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ",
      (int)self.webView.frame.size.width]];
```

Comment: I don't want to change the height and all.Just need to decrease the width of its content(providing some space at either end of the webView) and at the same time,the scrollBar should be at the right end of the webView frame.

Comment: you can use newBounds.size.width = your_value;

Comment: Ya but the scroll bar also will come inside the webView as it is in the attached picture.Please check the scroll bar present inside the red box.But what I want is, text should be within red box and the scroll bar should be near yellow box as represented in the black line in the picture.

Comment: Ypu can  `
    UIScrollView* currentScrollView;
    for (UIView* subView in self.myWebView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
            currentScrollView = (UIScrollView*)subView;
            currentScrollView.delegate = self;
        }
    }` and then [currentScrollView setContentOffset:offSet animated:YES];

Comment: Thank you. The above solution by The Tiger is working perfectly.But anyhow thank you so much.